# File manager which doesn't read or write anything unless asked to

Tags: linux, file-management

I am working with files stored in Google Drive by mounting the google drive in my file [google-drive-ocamlfuse](https://github.com/astrada/google-drive-ocamlfuse). My internet connection to Google Drive is not that fast. Typically I use Dolphin, but here it won't work well because it reads a lot of files to generate previews, estimate size, count the number of files, etc. which causes them to be loaded over the internet. I need a file manager for Linux which won't cause unnecessary reads or writes. In particular, it shouldn't try to read a file unless I explicitly open that file. I don't like text based multipane file managers like [Ranger](https://wiki.archlinux.org/title/Ranger) and [Midnight Commander](https://wiki.archlinux.org/title/Midnight_Commander). I would prefer a file manager similar to Dolphin or Windows Explorer.